# C# Regular Expressions not removing all unwanted characters?

Tags: c#, regex, string

The string I am trying to clean looks like

```
"\r\nPasswordchanged?\r\r\n"    string
```

I used this method

```
public string[] cleanStrings(string[] clean)
    {
        int j = 0;
        foreach (string data in clean)
        {
            string temp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(data, @"\r\n+", "");
            if (temp.Equals("&nbsp;"))
            {
                temp = "";
            }
            clean[j] = temp;
            j++;
        }
        return clean;
    }
```

The result was

```
"Passwordchanged?\r"    string
```

I thought my regex would remove all the `\r` and `\n`

Did I miss something?

Comment: if `\r` and `\n` are carriage return and linefeed, then why not just `Trim` it?

Comment: Your regular expression is checking for a `\r` immediately followed by a `\n` and removes them in pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a character class instead, specifically `[\r\n]`. This way any character in the character class will match.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(data, @"[\r\n]", "");
```

Your current pattern, `\r\n+`, will only match an `\r` followed by one or more `\n` characters, so it won't be able to match other stand-alone `\r` characters for example.